# How to show/hide fields in the admin UI depending on the value from another field with KeystoneJS Next?

Tags: keystonejs

I have a `Category` model set in `schema.ts` as follows:

```js
Category: list({
  fields: {
    name: text(),
    type: select({
      options: [
        { label: "MultipleChoice", value: "MultipleChoice" },
        { label: "Range", value: "Range" },
      ],
      defaultValue: "...",
      isRequired: true,
      isUnique: true,
      ui: { displayMode: "segmented-control" },
    }),
    from: integer(),
    to: integer(),
    options: text()
  },
})
```

And this renders these components in the admin UI:

[image: components in admin UI]

I'd like to show `from` and `to` fields only when `Range` is selected (hiding `options` field) and the other way around when `MultipleChoice` is selected. Is there a way to achieve that with Keystone Next?

I also tried another approach splitting the category types in different models and then relate them somehow with the `Category` model, but I'm not sure how to do so. Something like:

```js
CategoryRange: list({
  ui: {
    isHidden: true,
  },
  fields: {
    from: integer(),
    to: integer(),
  },
}),
CategoryMultipleChoice: list({
  ui: {
    isHidden: true,
  },
  fields: {
    options: text(),
  },
})
```

Comment: The most recent doc on Keystone 6 about conditional fields: [https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/document-fields#conditional-fields](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/document-fields#conditional-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional fields were [supported in Keystone 4](https://v4.keystonejs.com/api/field/options). They haven't been brought forward to Keystone 6 (aka. "Next") yet but they're on [the roadmap](https://keystonejs.com/updates/roadmap). I'd expect support for them to arrive in the next few months.

*Right now*, in Keystone 6, probably the best you could do would be to [create a custom field type](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/custom-fields) that collected the "type" and "from/to" fields together. This would let you define an interface in the Admin UI that implemented whatever presentation rules you liked.